# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path') in discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, typeerror

I was trying to send an attachment in discord.js v13 but I have this error, can someone help me please:

```
const rank = new canvacord.Rank()
    .setAvatar(member.user.displayAvatarURL({format: "jpg"}))
    .setUsername(member.user.username)
    .setCurrentXP(user.coinsInWallet)
    .setProgressBar("#57c478", "COLOR")
    .setUsername(member.user.username)
    .setDiscriminator(member.user.discriminator)

rank.build()
    .then(data => {
        const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(data, "MoneyBotCard.png");
        message.channel.send({files: [{attachement: [attachment]}]})
    });
```

In this code, it throws an error:

> ```
> node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessagePayload.js:240
>       if (thing.path) {
>                 ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
> ```

I also tried to run this but it changed nothing:

> npm install  path

Comment: Looks like a typo to me. `{attachement: [attachment]}` should be `{ attachement: attachment }`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Thanks for your response but it isn’t a typo error I verified if I do like you say, it sends me this:
 `throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's a typo. There is an extra `e` in `.send({files: [{attachement:`. It should be `.send({files: [{attachment:`. But the value of `attachment` should not be an array either.

Anyway, you don't even need to use `MessageAttachment`s. You can simply send the Buffer (`data`) like this:

```js
rank
  .build()
  .then((data) => message.channel.send({ files: [{ attachment: data }] }));
```

[image]